# What is the difference between DataBus and Publish/Subscribe design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

[DataBus Design Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?DataBusPattern)

[Publish/Subscribe Design Pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?PublishSubscribeModel)

To me they seem the same, what's the key difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the url you provided:

> DataBusPattern is related to, but not exactly the same as
>   PublishSubscribeModel. DataBusPattern decouples the sender and
>   receiver by adding an intermediary (the DataBus). In
>   PublishSubscribeModel, the sender and receiver must be aware of each
>   other.